# How to animate a div with the content it has inside?

Tags: html, css

Ok so here's what I am trying to do.

The green page there is a `div` with an image inside, the text and background are all an image, not made in `CSS`.

What I am trying to do is when mouse is over the `div`, I want the photo to shrink on the top left corner and I want some text to appear in where the div has been.

[image: Pic 1]

So here's what I have done so far.

```css
.projectcard {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.projectcard:hover {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Project Card -->
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="projectcard wow fadeInLeft">
    <img src="assets/images/projects/traversebg.png" style="border-radius: 20px;" class="imgs">
  </div>
  <div>
    Random Text.
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Project Card -->
```

This theoretically should work with making the photo shrink on top left, but when the `div` shrinks it detects as the mouse has left and goes full again. Not sure how to make video/gif of it, but it flickers like 50 times in a second.

My goal is to make it with as little `javascript` as possible, but I am open to any responsibility.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you could use float and position:absolute. possible example : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vYOOdmp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.projectcard {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

projectcard img{
    width:100%;
    
}    

.projectcard:hover img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  float:left;
  
}

   .projectcard:hover .textTest{
   float:left;
   width:300px
   }
```

```html
<!-- Project Card -->
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="projectcard wow fadeInLeft">
    <img src="assets/images/projects/traversebg.png" style="border-radius: 20px;" class="imgs">
  <div class="textTest">
    Random Text.Random Text.Random Text.Random Text.Random Text.Random Text.Random Text.Random Text.Random Text.Random Text.Random Text.Random Text.Random Text.Random Text.Random Text.
  </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- End Project Card -->
```

Comment: Code only answers are looked down upon at SO. Try to add some explanation of what you did.